# Why does printf cause deadlock with future.get while the cout does not?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I have some experience with MPI and CUDA and now I decided that it is high time to actually do some threading. I was learning the C++ Standard Library threading thingies and (based on a series of Youtube videos) I was building a simple piece of code which builds a job with std::packaged_task and sends it to job queue for worker threads to execute. Simple enough so far.

The problem started when I tried retrieving a result of the job via a future:

```
  printf_mutex.lock();
  printf("MAIN: Result of %i! is %i\n", 6, future_result_of_packaged_task.get()); // this causes deadlock!
  printf_mutex.unlock();
```

This locks the code forever!
But this works:

```
  int mah_result = future_result_of_packaged_task.get();
  printf_mutex.lock();
  printf("MAIN: Result of %i! is %i\n", 6, mah_result ); // this is okay
  printf_mutex.unlock();
```

As does this (which is what the youtuber did):

```
std::cout << future_result_of_packaged_task.get() << "\n"; //this is okay
```

**WHY DOES PRINTF() FAIL WHILE THE COUT WORKS CORRECTLY?**

I think understanding this problem could be very educational.

The entire code is simple enough (some libraries are not needed since i just lazy copypasted them from a previous toy code, but who cares):

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <thread>
#include <string>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <iostream>
#include <future>
#include <deque>

int factorial(int N, std::mutex& printf_mutex)
{
  int result = 1;
  for (int i = N; i > 1; --i) result *= i;
  printf_mutex.lock();
  printf("FACTORIAL: Result of %i! is %i\n", N, result);
  printf_mutex.unlock();
  return result;
}

void worker_thread( std::deque< std::packaged_task<int()> >& task_queue, std::mutex& task_queue_mutex, std::condition_variable& task_queue_cv, std::mutex& printf_mutex )
{
  std::unique_lock<std::mutex> task_queue_mutex_lock(task_queue_mutex);
  task_queue_cv.wait(task_queue_mutex_lock, [&](){return !task_queue.empty();} );
  printf_mutex.lock();
  printf("WORKER: I'm not sleeping anymore!\n"); // this is okay
  printf_mutex.unlock();
  std::packaged_task<int()> my_task = std::move( task_queue.front() );
  task_queue.pop_front();
  my_task();
}

int main()
{
  std::mutex printf_mutex;
  std::mutex task_queue_mutex;
  std::deque< std::packaged_task<int()> > task_queue;
  std::condition_variable task_queue_cv;

  std::thread a_thread( worker_thread, std::ref(task_queue), std::ref(task_queue_mutex), std::ref(task_queue_cv), std::ref(printf_mutex) );
  std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));

  std::packaged_task<int()> a_task( bind(factorial, 6, std::ref(printf_mutex)) );
  std::future<int> future_result_of_packaged_task = a_task.get_future();

  task_queue_mutex.lock();
  task_queue.push_back(std::move(a_task));
  task_queue_mutex.unlock();
  task_queue_cv.notify_one();
  printf_mutex.lock();
  printf("MAIN: Notification sent!\n"); // this is okay
  printf_mutex.unlock();

  //std::cout << future_result_of_packaged_task.get() << "\n"; //this is okay

  int mah_result = future_result_of_packaged_task.get();
  printf_mutex.lock();
  printf("MAIN: Result of %i! is %i\n", 6, mah_result ); // this is okay
  printf_mutex.unlock();

  printf_mutex.lock();
  //printf("MAIN: Result of %i! is %i\n", 6, future_result_of_packaged_task.get()); // this causes a deadlock!
  printf_mutex.unlock();

  a_thread.join();
  return 0;
}
```

Yes, I hate C++ iostream and yes i hate the std::locks, their mere existence offends the Occam's Razor. I also use horrible naming scheme for my toy codes. None of that matters for the question tough.

EDIT: So, the solution to the puzzle is not obvious from the accepted answer. I want to make it clear:
 1. Protecting the cout with printf_mutex makes it fail as well as printf. This suggests that the problem is either future.get() interfering with output mechanisms on my machine or the problem being a mutex clash / a race. When in doubt, always suspect a race, and notice that:
 2. future.get() is a blocking function. I *effectively* locked a mutex and went to sleep, which is asking for races. Where can that race happen tough? By experiment we know that it never happens in the worker thread. Where else could it happen?
**3. The answer is that the factorial also tries to lock printf_mutex and fails because the main always locks it first and then goes to sleep in future.get()**

The accepted answer is the one which provided the strongest/most complete clue.

Comment: While you're entitled to your opinion, there is no [`std::lock`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock) in this code so I'm not sure you are complaining about what you think you are. If you are complaining about the `.lock()` calls you are not suppose to use those functions anyway. You are expected to use [`std::unique_lock`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/unique_lock) and other RAII lock owning objects. Those functions are only exposed so you can implement your own lock types.

Comment: Is the line you've shown with `cout` used without a `mutex`? If it's not shown, I think it would be clearer to add it. If you are not using a `mutex` there then that explains the problem.

Comment: First of all, i am not complaining, I am asking an objective question. While indeed i forgot to add a mutex lock around the cout, this does not explain the problem at all. An explanation of a problem is a clear, objective, explicit step by step chronological description of what is happening and how is that different from what one thinks is happening. I do not see how your comments bring us any closer to that.

Comment: A complaint is "expressing dissatisfaction about something" so I hope you can see why someone might interpret *"Yes, I hate C++ iostream and yes i hate the std::locks"* as a complaint. As for my second comment, it's important to establish whether or not `cout` is synchronized in your actual code. If the actual code doesn't synchronize, it indeed explains your observations. If you simply forgot to include them here, it's important to fix the question as it may distract from the actual cause of what you are asking about.

Comment: It sounds like you interpreted me second comment as an attempt at answering your question. Comments are not for answering questions, they are for discussing the question. For example, I'm pointing out errors in the question. You should not expect a *"a clear, objective, explicit step by step chronological description"* in the comments. My comment is meant to indicates that the cause of the problem *might* be the missing synchronization. But I recognize that it might be simply an omission. It's meant to give you the opportunity to improve your question by clearing up this confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're having a race condition between `worker_thread` lock and the lowest `printf_mutex.lock()` (you can see it by placing a `std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));` before its `printf_mutex.lock();`) and also, if, by luck, `worker_thread` wins, you're having a mutex logic problem between the locking inside `factorial` and the lowest `printf_mutex.lock()`. `factorial` will be locked forever, because it's called after `printf_mutex` been locked. Either you lock inside `factorial` or lock before the outside `printf`.

Working or not with `std::cout` or with `printf` is just luck. `std::cout` can be slower or faster than `printf` depending on your optimization directive. And note that you're using `std::cout` without `printf_mutex.lock();` before, that's why it's working. Also, in the `printf` case that works, you're calling `.get()` before locking, that's why it works. Fix the race conditions and lock logics, then both `printf` and `std::cout` shall work.

---

Obs.: Prefer using RAII lock pattern and also consider using `std::recursive_mutex` for same thread locks, for printing, it can be very helpful.

Comment: Using RAII is exactly what prevents one from learning and understanding problems like these and results in much messier and less readable code anyway.
It cannot be a race between worker_thread and the main because the output clearly shows that the worker gets past the only mutex it has. I provided the entire code so that one can compile it for him/herself and check precisely that.
The "factorial will be locked forever, because it's called after printf_mutex been locked." is a good clue leading to the root of the problem:

Comment: - Main is stuck on get() because it is a blocking function, something which I did not think about but in the hindsight should've been obvious. Commenting out the output in factorial() makes all three variants of the output in main work as intended.

Answer (score 3):

you're holding `printf_mutex` so the task can't complete and `future_result_of_packaged_task.get()` never returns. Your other examples don't hold the mutex whilst calling `get` so don't deadlock.

Comment: This is only partially true, only cout example misses a mutex. Both printf cases have it.

Comment: yes but the second example doesn't hold the mutex whilst calling `get`

Comment: exactly! and this makes one think that printf for some wierd reason interferes with get. Apparently this is not the case however, the second answer provided the required clue.